# How Can I flatten my DTO into VO

Tags: dozer

Here is a sample simple scenario that I want to map. I have a DTO as follows

```
Class Person {
     String Name;
     List<Contact> contacts;
}
Class Contact {
 String type;  //values 'home', 'work', 'mobile' etc
 Phone number;
}
Class Phone {
   String areaCode;
   String number;
}
```

I need to map it to a VO object as follows

```
Class PersonVO {
   String Name;
   PhoneVO homePhone;
   PhoneVO workPhone;
}

Class PhoneVO {
 String areaCode;
 String number;
}
```

Is there an easier way to map them using dozer or I have to use customconvertors? how can I use default mapping for phone to phoneVO?

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot map Person DTO and PersonVO without using a CustomConverter,
   because Person's Phone 'number' variable gets it's value based on whether
   'type' variable contains values 'home' or 'work', and so on. Dozer cannot   handle such
   conditional cases.
2. However, default mapping for Phone and PhoneVO alone is very simple:

   ```
   <mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
         http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
       <mapping>
           <class-a>{package-name}.Phone</class-a>
           <class-b>{package-name}.PhoneVO</class-b>
      </mapping>
   </mappings>
   ```